# Python file executable error

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze

I did a fuel calculator program for a game with python and then I compiled to .exe with cx_Freeze. It converts it well to .exe and I can open the executable but when the script interacts with the user the window closes after pressing enter when the user introduce the requested information. 
This is one part of the code, after requesting some information to the user the program does some calculations but I think it's irrelevant because the problem is in the input. I want that the program doesn't close when the user press enter in the input of info requested.

```
import sys

COMBUSTIBLE=chr(raw_input("Introduce unidad de combustible: "))
DURACION=chr(raw_input("Introduce unidad de duracion: "))

if COMBUSTIBLE != "litros" and COMBUSTIBLE != "kilos" and DURACION != "vueltas" and DURACION != "tiempo" and DURACION != "km":
    print "Error: Ambos argumentos son invalidos"
    print "Primer argumento debe ser 'litros' o 'kilos'"
    print "Segundo argumento debe ser 'tiempo' o 'vueltas' o 'km'"
    sys.exit(1)
elif COMBUSTIBLE != "litros" and COMBUSTIBLE != "kilos":
    print "Error: Primer argumento invalido"
    print "Primer argumento debe ser 'litros' o 'kilos'"
    sys.exit(2)
elif DURACION != "tiempo" and DURACION != "vueltas" and DURACION != "km":
    print "Error: Segundo argumento invalido"
    print "Segundo argumento debe ser 'tiempo' o 'vueltas' o 'km'"
    sys.exit(3)
else:
    pass

# TIPO 1 - LITROS - VUELTAS 
if COMBUSTIBLE == "l" and DURACION == "v":
    # DATA REQUEST
    RACE_DURATION=int(raw_input("Introduce el total de vueltas de la carrera: "))
    CAR_FUEL=float(raw_input("Introduce los litros totales del coche: "))
    FUEL_PER_LAP=float(raw_input("Introduce el consumo medio en litros por vuelta: "))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window will be closed right after your proggram finished executing. So if you want the window stays open you should remove sys.exit() statements and add something at the end of your script like:

```
input("Press any key to exit: ")
```

in Python 3 or

```
raw_input("Press any key to exit: ")
```

in Python 2

Comment: I removed sys.exit() lines and added: raw_input("Press any key to exit: ") at the end of the file. But the same happens. First the program show to the user this COMBUSTIBLE=chr(raw_input("Introduce unidad de combustible: ")), the two possible values for COMBUSTIBLE are "litros" or "kilos". I write litros and I press enter, the cmd window closes. The script works well when I execute the python file but not the executable.

Comment: Did you re create the exe?

Comment: Yes, I created the exe of the python file with cx_Freeze. I can open the exe well, the problem is when the script interact with me and I have to press enter to introduce the value of the requested information at the begining..

And yes, I remove the last exe and re create again the exe but the same problem.

Comment: Can you paste full script? Cant say anymore with that.

Comment: Ok I will paste it or upload it.. it has more than 200 lines.

Comment: that link need key

Comment: key: !-VQoer7wpUythb_MLbdKAmj99TZz_s8OqEvKZst1rqY

Comment: 1 - chr() function expects an int but raw_input() returns str so you should remove chr(). If you want to get first character of input use raw_input()[0]. 2 - You check COMBUSTIBLE and DURACION both as a string (like litros etc) and as a one character str (like l etc). They cant be both at same time. Either use both litros or check as COMBUSTIBLE[0] != "l".

Comment: oh true :( I was doing this script after a long time without using python so I failed in the command! I will try it calmly tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for helping me alpert! Now the program functions very well as I expected! I changed the chr to str, then I add raw_input("Press any key to exit: ") after every type of calculation to tell the program to stop before the exit given and I modified all the values of the variables in the condition lines. Thanks again! SOLVED.